# How to constrait a generic class to work with just two classes

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints, communication

I have a generic class modeling a protocol that encapsulates other protocols. All the protocols implement a specific interface but this generic class must contain only one of two of these protocols as in the real world the other combinations do not exist.

Is there a way to specify the two allowed classes?

Currently I have:

```
public class ProtocolEncapsulator<TContainedCommand> : IBaseCommand where TContainedCommand : IBaseCommand
```

But this allows users of the framework to create non-sense combinations.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give me an example of these non-sense combinations? I think I didn't get it.

Comment: Can you create a separate interface that only those two types implement?  I don't believe [type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) let you "or" the constraints, and you can't overload a method based on the type constraint.

Comment: @ConradClark: What I mean is that the ProtocolEncapsulator just encapsulates 2 kinds of protocols because this is a protocol created by a manufacturer for their own protocols (and they have just 2). As all the protocols we support (from they and others) implement the IBaseCommand you could encapsulate things that have no sense.

Comment: @BrianS: I could but I don't feel very good creating a 'fake' interface  just for these two interfaces, but maybe this is the only solution.

Comment: That is the best way I can think of if you want to make it a compile-time constraint (as I understand the question).  Otherwise, you could use reflection to examine the type and raise an exception if it isn't one of the two options, but that leads to a runtime error, which is less desirable than a compile-time constraint in my opinion.

Comment: Also, in my opinion, this is a good use case for an interface - I like to consider interfaces ideal for classifying objects based on what they 'can do' (rather than 'is a' for inheritance).  And in this case, you have 2 class that 'can do' something that other, similar classes "can't do", so it seems an ideal use of an interface to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating an interface that is implemented only by the two protocols and then use a type constraint to restrict the method in question.

Something like:

```
public interface IExclusiveCommand : IBaseCommand
{
    void ExclusiveMethod();  //Not necessary if there are no differences between Base and Exclusive
}

public class ProtocolEncapsulator<TContainedCommand> : IBaseCommand where TContainedCommand : IExclusiveCommand
{
}
```

While it does add another interface and might be viewed as adding complexity, I believe it actually simplifies things by making them more explicit and clear.  And the compile-time restriction makes it more maintainable and easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Agree. But when I implemented this I realized that I can replace the generic type directly with the new interface and I don't need anymore a generic class. Thanks anyway.